# Como customizar o Arrow do Swiper React.js em jsx ou styled.component

Tags: css, react, front-end, styled-components

Eu quero customizar os arrows do [swiper](https://swiperjs.com/react/), mas eu nao achei nada na documentacao.

Este é o codigo do meu navigation:

```js
 const params = {
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
    slidesPerView: 7,
    spaceBetween: 5,
    shouldSwiperUpdate: true,
    pagination: {
      clickable: true,
    },
  };
```

E está exibindo dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso mudar a cor do arrow, e seu tamanho. Eu queria usar o style={{}}, ou o styled.component.

Comment: Você está utilizando a library https://swiperjs.com/react? Se não, poderia enviar o link?

Comment: Claro, estou usando essa aqui
https://swiperjs.com/react/

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Na sua essência o swiperjs do react não possui meios de trabalhar com styledComponents ou style, conforme a [documentação](https://swiperjs.com/react/#styles) deles, as opções disponíveis são:

- manipular os estilos do CSS
- trabalhar com LESS
- trabalhar com SCSS

Uma solução simples e rápida seria adicionar no seu HTML o trecho css abaixo:

```css
div.swiper-button-prev,
div.swiper-button-next {
   color: red;
}
```

Veja os [exemplos disponíveis](https://swiperjs.com/demos/) para mais informação